# Errors when install pocketsphinx 0.7 on Windows 7 using Cygwin

Tags: build, cygwin, cmusphinx

I tried to install pocketsphinx version 0.7 on my Windows 7 using Cygwin (I have installed sphinxbase 0.7). I face some errors with "make" command. Please help me. Thank you very much !!!

Makefile:316: recipe for target `pocketsphinx_continuous.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [pocketsphinx_continuous.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/cygdrive/d/Cao_Hoc/Luan_Van/test_Android_ASR/test_1/pocketsphinx-0.7/src/programs'
Makefile:271: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/cygdrive/d/Cao_Hoc/Luan_Van/test_Android_ASR/test_1/pocketsphinx-0.7/src'
Makefile:372: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

---

This is the full log: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?34577vncq1rqu7b

Comment: When you have build errors you need to provide the full log which contain the reason of the error and the description of it, not just last 3 lines which are meaningless. The more information you provide the faster you will get answer.

Comment: I guess the reason is: checking for pkg-config... no
checking for GStreamer... checking for sphinxbase in /cygdrive/d/Cao_Hoc/Luan_Van/test_Android_ASR/test_1/pocketsphinx-0.7/../sphinxbase... no (when running the ./configure). But I am not sure. How to fix it ? Please support me. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

For Cygwin do not use version 0.7. Download latest snapshot, it should compile better

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download